# replacing precise string in python

Tags: python, string, replace

Given this seemingly straightforward string replace function python

```
sample_str = 'fl'
print(sample_str.replace('fl','florida')
result:  'florida'
```

How to avoid this result, however:

```
sample_lst = ['fl', 'florida']
for word in sample_lst:
    new_word = word.replace('fl', 'florida')
    print(new_word)
    'florida'
    'floridaorida'
```

Point being, I have a huge pandas df and am trying to replace things like 'fl' but only where 'fl' occurs in a string by itself, not when it occurs as part of some other string like 'florida' or 'nfl' etc.

I tried using a regex string like this r'fd(?![0|_| ])'. That didn't work.  This seems like a basic question so I presume I am overlooking some python fundamental long lost to my memory.  Any ideas pythonistas out there?

Comment: I would recommend you to use simple regular expression, like [`\bfl\b`](https://regex101.com/r/ykN8f8/1)
. Take a look on [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module.

Comment: Why don't you just check if `word == "fl"` and replace only if that is true?

Comment: Something like `^(fl)$` limits the string with start and end anchors.  Have you tried this convention?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  Any regex tutorial shows you the start-word and end-word syntax.

Comment: Thanks so much for the generous time spent in response everyone. I’ve used regex in web scraping tools, pandas, NLTK and just had one of those situations where I was looking at the problem from one perspective and missed some great options which you all provided. I’ll be trying these out on regex101 tonight. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import re
search_str = 'fl'
my_strings = ['fl', 'florida']
for string in my_strings:
    if re.match(f'^{search_str}$', string):
        print('florida')
    else:
        print(string)
```

That way you can be a little bit more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

Just check if word is equivilent to `'fl'` - if it is, make it into `'florida'`:

```
sample_lst = ['fl', 'florida']
for word in sample_lst:
    new_word = word
    if word == 'fl':
        new_word = 'florida'
    print(new_word)
```

or...

```
sample_lst = ['fl', 'florida']
for word in sample_lst:
    new_word = 'florida' if word == 'fl' else word
    print(new_word)
```

if you want to store the result in a new list, you could even do list comprehension!!

```
sample_lst = ['fl', 'florida']
result = ['florida' if word == 'fl' else word for word in sample_lst]
```

On the other hand, if you want to check if there is a word (it can be surrounded by spaces), you can use regex:

```
import re
sample_lst = ['fl', 'florida']
for word in sample_lst:
    new_word = re.sub(r'\bfl\b', 'florida', word)
    print(new_word)
```

and list comprehension (of course we need list comprehension):

```
import re
sample_lst = ['fl', 'florida']
result = [re.sub(r'\bfl\b', 'florida', word) for word in sample_lst]
```